# Retrieving contact number from JSON to send SMS

Tags: android, sms, android-json

I have contact numbers in local `JSON` file. And I have to send SMS by retrieving the contact number from `JSON`. I have no idea how to make it work, please help me.

**My JSON file:**

```
{"Person Name": "abc", "Person Phone": "1234567890"}
```

Here is my method in which I am sending the SMS to fetched conrtact.

```
protected void sendsms(String Person_Phone,String message)
{


    Toast.makeText(this, "sms sent to"+Person_Phone,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
try {

    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(Person_Phone, null, message, null, null);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + getString(R.string.smsfailed),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your JSON here?

Comment: wat  problem u r facing.Just use  key and get the value

Comment: its giving..SMS sent to null in a toast message.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject((String) result);

String personName = jsonObj.getString("Person Name");
String phoneNumber = jsonObj.getString("Person Phone");
```

Comment: SMS is not sent...I have written a separate method for sending SMS and giving a toast to see if SMS is sent but its not sent..i have posted my SMS method

Comment: write the complete code... from fetching JSON data to sending sms.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{\"Person Name\": \"abc\", \"Person Phone\": \"1234567890\"}");
String person_Name = obj.getString("Person Name");
String phone_Number = obj.getString("Person Phone");
```

Comment: I have a similar use case here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62239517/android-deliver-plain-text-data-to-another-app-user-with-clickable-image-via-sm  Would appreciate any ideas, thoughts that you could offer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Jsonparser parser=new Jsonparser;
JSONObject obj = parser.parse("{\"Person Name\": \"abc\", \"Person Phone\": \"1234567890\"}");

String phone_no=obj.get("Person Phone").toString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
JSONObject myJsonObject = new JSONObject("{\"Person Name\": \"abc\", \"Person Phone\": \"1234567890\"}");
String number = myJsonObject.optString("Person Phone").toString();
String name = myJsonObject.optString("Person Name").toString();
sendSms(number,someMessage);
```

In sendSms do this:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
```

Include the following permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```